# Maximum password length

Tags: security, password

Is there a maximum password length on unix systems?

If so, what is that limit and is it distribution dependent?

Comment: Answered here http://superuser.com/questions/148971/what-is-the-max-length-of-password-on-unix-linux-system

Comment: today most distribution will use sha256/512 older will more likely use md5

Comment: The days of DES where the password was truncated at the 8th byte are long gone. Now, that's down to the limitations in the applications where you enter your password. For instance, for HTTP basic auth, IIRC, the max HTTP header length is 1024 bytes, so taking into account other overhead, your password can't be much over 600 bytes if it needs to go in there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depends on which particular `crypt()` algorithm one is using:

- modified DES: 8 ASCII characters
- MD5: Unlimited length
- Blowfish: 56 bytes
- NT Hash: Please don't use this one
- SHA256/512: Unlimited length

More information: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crypt_%28C%29